# Connecting to Webdisk on OSX 10.9 (mavericks)

Tags: macos, webdav

Just got a new mac with OSX 10.9. Trying to connect to my hosting provider via webdisk. On my older Mac with 10.7.5 it works fine. I copied the same shortcut to my new computer, as well as a direct connection via Finder, and cannot connect.

Finder -> Go -> Connect to Server

I enter https://mydomain.com:2078

I get the error "There was a problem connecting to the server "mydomain.com".

Anyone know of something different in 10.9 re: Web Disk / Webdav?

Answer (score 0):

I found a potential solution here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5559374

Apparently if you use port 2077, it will work, e.g. connect to

https://mydomain.com:2077 instead of the usual 2078.

I don't quite understand why changing to the non-usual port should work, as that port is a property of the webdav server, not my mac, but nonetheless it seems to work.